# Help! front wheel brake doesn't brake (Shimano)

Tags: brakes

when I squeeze my front wheel hand brakes, the lever goes all the way to the grip on my handle very easily. It feels like there is no force to it. On top of that, the brake pads do not move at all when I try to brake. what is wrong with it? Please help me.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of brakes you have. Hydraulic or cable actuated? Center pull, side pull, cantilever? If those words don't make sense a nice clear picture of the front brake would help. If we can get some detail we can provide a better answer.

Comment: They are V brakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds obvious, but first ensure the cable is securely attached to the caliper by the pinch bolt.

Check that the brake housing that the front brake cable runs inside is properly fitted into the brake lever. If the housing has come loose the cable has nothing to pull against and will not operate the brake calipers.

If you have v-brake calipers, check that the curved metal 'noodle' is properly fitted into the caliper. The noodle can be popped out to spread the calipers to allow removal of the wheel.

It's also possible that the cable has snapped inside the housing, or the cable head has broken off.

Comment: it is properly fitted but it still will not brake.

Comment: Since the cable is attached at the pinch bolt the cable is either not attached at the lever or it's broken inside the cable housing. Or, the cable is very lose and needs tightening.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out David!